# Pythonic way to sort array of string by an associated number

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

Need to sort HOST string array by its associated float speed

Is there nice way to get array from sorted tuples?
Can I eliminate ordered array?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def getSpeed(url):
    if url == 'h1':
         return 0.522611856461
     elif url == 'h2':
         return 0.438368797302
     elif url == 'h3':
         return 0.443703174591

def orderHosts():
    hostInfo = []
    ordered = []
    hosts = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
    for host in hosts:
        hostInfo.append( (host, getSpeed(host)) )

    print hostInfo
    return ordered

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("orderedHosts {}".format(orderHosts()))
```

output:

```
[('h1', 0.522611856461), ('h2', 0.438368797302), ('h3', 0.443703174591)]

orderedHosts []
```

Comment: Why do you have a function just to store values? Why not use a `dictionary`? What exacly are you trying to do?

Comment: function orderedHosts needs to return array of host ordered by getSpeed value. `hostInfo` could be a dictionary instead of array in which I am appending tuples, so append would become like `hostInfo[speed] = host`. I thought it would easier to sort tuples.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I was talking about the getSpeed function

Comment: In my actual software program (for Check Cashing) the little getSpeed function is an elaborate series of XML doc request, respose via Requests--would make your hair curl. I just need sort tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter of `sort` or `sorted` to set a function that is called before sorting. In your case, `sorted(hosts, key=getSpeed)` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) builtin function takes a `key=` argument. You can use that to provide a function that will return the comparison key (in this case, the speed) like so:

```
def getSpeed(host):
    ... as you had it
    return speed

hosts = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
ordered_hosts = sorted(hosts, key=getSpeed)
```

Comment: In my actual program the getSpeed function returns a Response object from Requests that is an XML doc with possible error status, etc. There is a Response.duration attribute but no simple function like getSpeed. I ment to try and ask about sorting array of tuples, converting tuples into array OR sorting dictionary, converting dictionary into array.